# Combine Queries in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am making a series of queries to get filtered variations of a queryset. Is there a simpler way to do this where I'm not hitting the DB 6 times and instead just using the initial call?

```
data['os']['today'] = Page.objects.all()
data['os']['pro'] = Page.objects.filter(premium_plan=PlanType.PRO).count()
data['os']['yesterday'] = Page.objects.filter(created__lt=within_last_day).count()
data['os']['week'] = Page.objects.filter(created__lt=within_last_week).count()
data['os']['new_pro'] = Page.objects.filter(upgrade__cancelled_date__isnull=True, upgrade__activated_date=within_last_day)
data['os']['new_top_pages'] = Page.objects.filter(created__gt=within_last_day).extra(select={'total_fans':'facebook_count + twitter_count'}, order_by=('-total_fans',))[:10]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are getting all pages:

```
pages = Page.objects.all() # Page.objects.select_related() if we want filtering on related objects fields
```

Then you can fetching other types of pages without additional DB query:

```
# it will not call the database
data['os']['yesterday'] = pages.filter(created__lt=within_last_day).count()
data['os']['week'] = pages.filter(created__lt=within_last_week).count()
...
```

If you get a page through the filter method, subsequent calls to the filter will work with the first fetching set:

```
pages = Page.objects.filter(id__in=(1,2,3))  # we have pages in db with ids in 1,2,3,4,5
pages_additional = pages.filter(condition) #Here we are working with objects with ids 1,2,3
```

If at first you do not fetch all the records(Page.objects.all()), it is impossible to obtain additional data that were not included in the first fetching set without any additional queries.